# Migrate Content from old Sharepoint 2007 site to new Sharepoint 2007 site

Tags: migration

I'm new to sharepoint, and i've been asked to migrate some (not all) content from an old sharepoint site to a new site.

The old site and the new site do not have the same structure and they both consist of multiple subsites as well as many document libraries and lists. Most of the content that needs migrating will be document libraries or lists and they will need to be re-parented (due to the different structure in the new site).

I've spent a little time investigating what options I have, and it seems that my best course of action is to use the "SharePoint Content Deployment and Migration API".

Can someone please confirm (given my requirements) if this is indeed the best route for me to take. I'm just worried that I could be spending a lot of time attempting this solution when there could be a much better solution available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good success using the stsadm extensions located [here](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2009/02/downloads.html)

They use the migration api's and allow an easy way to backup and restore doc libs and lists to different site collections or farms.

Comment: Thanks Steve,

This looks like a much better approach. It seems it makes use of the api i was planning on using anyway which should save me some headaches.

Thanks again!